# save json list into file with multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x

I need to save a list (*results*) of json object into file, so each element of the list must be saved in one line. The list of object is saved in a file (*data_file*). I am using the below code :

```
# some code here
fi =open(final_results, "a+")

for i in range(1,20)
    #some code here 
    with open(targetpath, 'r') as data_file:
         json_data = data_file.read()
    results = json.loads(json_data)
    for en in results:
        json.dump(en, fi)
        fi.write("\n")
```

At the end of collecting data, the  fi can contain some 5Go.
My question : is there a more optimal way to do this work?

Comment: but you are saving an invalid json. you'll have to add `[ ]` at start and end of `final_results`. Am I wrong?

Comment: results contains a list. with the loop (for), I browse each element of the results which is string. With dump function, I convert this string to json object before adding it to final_results file.

Comment: final_results won't be a valid json,  are you ok with that? Add short input with expected output to make things easier